# R select email addresses with > 2 similar start dates in a year

Tags: r

I would like to set unique email addresses with more than 2 *similar* start years in a dataframe in R to NA in a new column.

```
start_year email
2016       a@a.com
2016       a@a.com
2016       a@a.com
2015       a@a.com
2015       a@a.com
2014       a@a.com
2015       b@b.com
2014       b@b.com
2014       b@b.com
2015       c@c.com
```

Result (a@a.com has 3 similar start years 2016 and is therefore set to NA in a new column):

```
start_year email    email_new
2016       a@a.com  NA
2016       a@a.com  NA
2016       a@a.com  NA
2015       a@a.com  NA
2015       a@a.com  NA
2014       a@a.com  NA
2015       b@b.com  b@b.com
2014       b@b.com  b@b.com
2014       b@b.com  b@b.com
2015       c@c.com  c@c.com
```

So far I have this which gives an error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.:

```
result <- df %>%
  group_by(email) %>%
  select(length(unique(start_year)) > 2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean >=2 start dates yes?

Comment: I mean >2 start years or >= 3 start years

Comment: I dont get this. why `b@b.com` isn't NA?

Comment: b@b.com has 1 start year in 2015 and 2 start years in 2014. 2 start years in 2014 is not more than 2 and therefore no NA

Comment: It is a about setting emails to NA which have more than 2 _similar_ start years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, as far as I understood it, you have two conditions for converting `email` to NA.

1)At least 3 of the `start_year` are the same

2) There are more than 2 observations

```
 df %>% 
    group_by(email) %>% 
    mutate(new = ifelse(length(which(table(start_year) > 2)) > 0 & n()>2, 'NA', as.character(email)))

#Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
#Groups: email [3]

#  start_year   email     new
#       <int>   <chr>   <chr>
#1       2016 a@a.com    <NA>
#2       2016 a@a.com    <NA>
#3       2016 a@a.com    <NA>
#4       2015 b@b.com b@b.com
#5       2014 b@b.com b@b.com
#6       2014 b@b.com b@b.com
#7       2015 c@c.com c@c.com
```

Adding another `2014` for `b@b.com`, thus making 3 same years for that email, then

```
df1 %>% 
     group_by(email) %>% 
     mutate(new = ifelse(length(which(table(start_year) > 2)) > 0 & n()>2, 'NA', as.character(email)))

#Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
#Groups: email [3]

#  start_year   email     new
#       <dbl>   <chr>   <chr>
#1       2016 a@a.com      NA
#2       2016 a@a.com      NA
#3       2016 a@a.com      NA
#4       2015 b@b.com      NA
#5       2014 b@b.com      NA
#6       2014 b@b.com      NA
#7       2014 b@b.com      NA
#8       2015 c@c.com c@c.com
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(start_year = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2015L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2015L), email = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("a@a.com", "b@b.com", "c@c.com"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("start_year", 
"email"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

dput(df1)
structure(list(start_year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2015), email = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("a@a.com", "b@b.com", "c@c.com"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), .Names = c("start_year", "email"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this gives an error "Error: incompatible types, expecting a character vector". Any idea?

Comment: hmm...try wrapping the first argument of `ifelse` to `as.numeric` , i.e. `mutate(new = ifelse(as.numeric(length(unique(start_year)) ==1 & n()>2), NA, as.character(email)))`

Comment: Same error.. What does work is putting NA in "", I have used FALSE: mutate(new = ifelse(length(unique(start_year)) ==1 & n()>2, "FALSE", as.character(email))). I am now testing if the correct email addresses are put to FALSE

Comment: It is not giving the correct results unfortunately, due to condition 1 "all the start_year are the same". This should be more than 2 observations of the same start year. I will edit my question, sorry for the unclarity

Comment: so for `b@b.com` if the start_years were: `2015, 2014, 2014, 2014`, then we would put NA?

Comment: Yes! Any idea how to achieve this with dplyr?

Comment: well, that just raised the difficulty significantly...will try

Comment: Thank you, looking forward to your answer

Comment: @aju_k ok I think I got it. Please check

Comment: Thanks! I'll get back to you in a couple of hours (have to do something in between unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to do this in `base R`

```
tbl <- table(df$email, df$start_year) > 2
df$email_new <- ifelse(df$email %in% rownames(tbl)[row(tbl)[which(tbl)]], NA,
                                                        as.character(df$email))
df
#  start_year  email    email_new
#1        2016 a@a.com      <NA>
#2        2016 a@a.com      <NA>
#3        2016 a@a.com      <NA>
#4        2015 a@a.com      <NA>
#5        2015 a@a.com      <NA>
#6        2014 a@a.com      <NA>
#7        2015 b@b.com   b@b.com
#8        2014 b@b.com   b@b.com
#9        2014 b@b.com   b@b.com
#10       2015 c@c.com   c@c.com
```

Finding out the frequency for every email, every year (`table(df$email, df$start_year)`) . Finding out the names of `email` which has frequency more than 2 for any particular year and converting that row as `NA`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'email' `if` the `length` of the `unique` elements (`uniqueN`) is greater than 2, assign it as `NA` or `else` 'email' to create the 'email_new'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, email_new := if(uniqueN(start_year)>2) NA_character_ else email,  by = email]

df1
#    start_year   email email_new
#1:       2016 a@a.com        NA
#2:       2016 a@a.com        NA
#3:       2016 a@a.com        NA
#4:       2015 a@a.com        NA
#5:       2015 a@a.com        NA
#6:       2014 a@a.com        NA
#7:       2015 b@b.com   b@b.com
#8:       2014 b@b.com   b@b.com
#9:       2014 b@b.com   b@b.com
#10:      2015 c@c.com   c@c.com
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(start_year = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L), email = c("a@a.com", "a@a.com", 
"a@a.com", "a@a.com", "a@a.com", "a@a.com", "b@b.com", "b@b.com", 
"b@b.com", "c@c.com")), .Names = c("start_year", "email"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: This does not seem to set any email_new to NA unfortunately. Any idea?

Comment: @aju_k Based on the example in my 'data' and output in my post, it is changing to 'NA'

Comment: I see that, I'll try to convert my dataframe typeof columns similar to yours

Comment: @aju_k  It is the output of `dput`. Please check if the `email` column is `factor` in your dataset,

Comment: I receive the following error: Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(tmp), , `:=`(email_new, if (uniqueN(Start_Year) >  : 
  Type of RHS ('character') must match LHS ('integer'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1). Any idea?

Comment: @aju_k I would think you have a `factor` class for 'email'.  I would change to `character` class before doing the `if` i.e. setDT(df1)[, email := as.character(email)]` and then use the code in my post

Comment: Your solution works perfectly in the df1 your provide, but I can't get it to work properly in my 'real' dataframe unfortunately